# Capture string before and string after substring into named capturing group

Tags: regex, capture-group

I'd like to capture into named groups a series of percentages which occasionally have an erroneous '-' after a decimal point

```
group1 2.3% / group2 4.-787% / group3 7.-65%
```

I can capture the numbers just fine (see [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/pOu7Xs/2/)) but I'd like to be able to get rid of the '-' characters when i capture the group. For example, the above string would result in.

```
Group 'group 1': 2.3
Group 'group 2': 4.787
Group 'group 3': 7.65
```

Comment: You can't do it using a single capture group. You can capture the two parts fore and aft of the dash in separate groups though. Why not replace such dashes with nothing to remove them before then capturing the target input?

Comment: As @Bohemian mentions, use a regex such as [**`(?<=\.)-(?=\d)`**](https://regex101.com/r/LdO3z8/1/) and get rid of them altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Bohemian states, you can capture the two parts before and after the dash with a regex like:

```
(\d+\.)-?(\d+)%
```

Next you can concatenate groups 1 and 2 together to get your result.

Look at [Example 1](https://regex101.com/r/pOu7Xs/3)